# Dataframe fill leaving behind null value?

Tags: python, pandas

As the title implies, after using the ffill, i'm having a null value get left behind in the dataframe. Here's a sample of a relevant portion of the dataframe:

```
data = {'03_15_2019': {0: u'tariff rail rates for unit and shuttle train shipments1',
  1: np.nan,
  2: np.nan,
  3: np.nan,
  4: u'unit train'},
 u'bushel2': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: u'         bushel2', 4: np.nan},
 u'destination_region3': {0: np.nan,
  1: np.nan,
  2: np.nan,
  3: u'Destination region3',
  4: np.nan},
 u'fuel_surcharge_per_car': {0: np.nan,
  1: u'Fuel surcharge per car',
  2: np.nan,
  3: np.nan,
  4: np.nan},
 u'metric_ton': {0: np.nan,
  1: np.nan,
  2: u'Tariff plus surcharge per:',
  3: u'     metric ton',
  4: np.nan},
 u'origin_region3': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: u'Origin region3', 4: np.nan},
 u'rate_car': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: u'Tariff', 3: u'rate/car', 4: np.nan},
 u'y_y4': {0: np.nan, 1: u'Percent', 2: u'change', 3: u'Y/Y4', 4: np.nan}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Here's the code i'm trying to use:

```
df[df.columns[0]].ffill(inplace = True)
df[df.columns[0]] = df[df.columns[0]].str.lower()
values = df.index[df[df.columns[0]].str.contains("train")].tolist()
```

the error is returned on the third line as:

```
ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values
```

when i check the dataframe, it gives me this:

```
0     tariff rail rates for unit and shuttle train s...
1     tariff rail rates for unit and shuttle train s...
2     tariff rail rates for unit and shuttle train s...
3                                                   NaN
4                                            unit train
```

and what makes it weirder, is that if i were to rerun the code above in a new cell of jupyter notebook, it'll work. It's only on the first run that it doesn't work.

Comment: Can not reproduced your problem

Comment: You should include the code you've used to create a sample dataframe

Comment: added sample dataframe

Comment: Cannot reproduce with given code

Answer (score 0):

```py
df[df.columns[0]].ffill(inplace = True)
```

This line replaces the NaN in the first column. When you check the df after this line it will not be what you posted above.

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.DataFrame.ffill` stads for forward fill, meaning that if the first items of your column are `NaN` those will not be filled (nothing to propagate forward).

So basically:

```
data = {'a': [1,2,None, None], 'b': [None, 2, None, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.ffill()
```

will result in:

```
     a    b
0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  2.0
2  2.0  2.0
3  2.0  4.0
```

You may want to follow `ffill` with a `fillna` to handle those cases differently